# ROS: Rviz - publish point - subscriber - get x,y coordinates

Tags: ros

I am trying to get x,y coordinates from rviz and get it subscribed to a topic So when i do publish point and click on any free space in rviz i get its x,y,z coordinates in the topic /clicked_point I want to subscribe to these points and print it on the terminal. The code i have is a simple subscriber to the topic /clicked_point.

But when i run the code i get x,y as 0.0 and not the desired coordinates that i click.

Can someone help me please in looking at my code. I suspect it has to do something with the point stamped attributes.

Please let me know

Full code

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
import tf
import random
import numpy as np

global x,y,z
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
z = 0.0

def callback(msg): 
    point = PointStamped()
    point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    point.header.frame_id = "/map"
    point.point.x = x 
    point.point.y = y 
    point.point.z = z
    rospy.loginfo("coordinates:x=%f y=%f" %(x,y))

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('goal_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rospy.point_pub = rospy.Subscriber('/clicked_point', PointStamped, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

In terminal

```
varun-flox@varunflox:~/Desktop$ ./ros_localisation_subscriber.py 
[INFO] [1607606216.839750]: coordinates:x=0.000000 y=0.000000
[INFO] [1607606221.911950]: coordinates:x=0.000000 y=0.000000
```

In another terminal with rostopic echo /clicked_point

```
varun-flox@varunflox:~$ rostopic echo /clicked_point 
header: 
  seq: 31
  stamp: 
    secs: 1607606021
    nsecs: 774185596
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: -4.99073648453
  y: -4.93864154816
  z: -0.00288152694702
---
header: 
  seq: 32
  stamp: 
    secs: 1607606216
    nsecs: 838675541
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: -4.98981332779
  y: -4.96337604523
  z: -0.0113334655762
---
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your assignment of the variables in the callback function.
See

```
def callback(msg): 
    x = msg.point.x
    y = msg.point.y
    z = msg.point.z
    rospy.loginfo("coordinates:x=%f y=%f" %(x,y))
```

Fir explanation the msg variable ahnded over as paramter for the callback function wraps the PointStamped msg type and can be unpacked seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified and tested, Thank me later.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped

global x,y,z
def callback(msg): 
    rospy.loginfo("coordinates:x=%f y=%f" %(msg.point.x,msg.point.y))

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('goal_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rospy.point_pub = rospy.Subscriber('/clicked_point', PointStamped, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```